# dealing with "possible null reference return" when implementing external interfaces on projects that enable nullable

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have the following interface that needs to get implemented, returning default if not finding the role generates warning CS8603 Possible null reference return.

```
    public async Task<ApplicationRole> FindRoleByIdAsync(string roleId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
       //find the role based on ID return it if found else
       return default;
    }
```

I can't change the interface and make it nullable as my influence over  Microsoft are not at that level... so I guess update it with an annotation (does not make the warning go away)

```
    [return: MaybeNull]
    public async Task<ApplicationRole> FindRoleByIdAsync(string roleId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
       //find the role based on ID return it if found.. else 
       return default;
    }
```

what is the correct way to implement this, any suggestions?

Comment: You're returning a class (reference type) so the `default` of it is indeed `null`. If you really want to do it that way, you'll have to let the compiler know that it is intended to return `null` by changing the return type from `Task<ApplicationRole>` to `Task<ApplicationRole?>`.

Comment: @RacilHilan The interface does not specify the ? therefore I get a wrong interface implementation warning if I do that

Comment: Then you should not return `null`, it's really that basic. If you're implementing an interface, you need to implement it appropriately. If you want to implement it in your own way, then you should create your own interface.

Comment: using the interface in your code would return null  when  calling IRoleStore<T>.FindRoleByIdAsync using the MS implementation as it uses FirstOrDefault() so brake the behaviour is a no-go, suppress the warning I think is the only option (against company policy...)

Comment: If the interface really does accept a null return, but it is declared to not accept a null return, you should consider filing a bug on the owner of the interface (even if it is Microsoft) and suppressing the warning about the nullable return in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to not return a Null value

```
public async Task<ApplicationRole> FindRoleByIdAsync(string roleId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
       //find the role based on ID return it if found.. else 
       return default ?? new ApplicationRole();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For deep-dive visit [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings). As per MSDN:

> Apply the null forgiving operator ! to the expression to force the state to not-null.

```
public async Task<ApplicationRole> FindRoleByIdAsync(String roleId, CancellationToke cancellationToken = default)
{
    //Your code
    return default!;
}
```

or

```
public async Task<ApplicationRole> FindRoleByIdAsync(String roleId, CancellationToke cancellationToken = default)
{
    //Your code
    return null!;
}
```